# MVC - How to pause a loop in a Controller for user input, then continue once it's passed through

Tags: c#, loops, asp.net-core-mvc, user-input, wait

I'm developing a personal frontend for my Media Server that entails the use of Entity Framework Core, and adding the Movies within my Media Server to a database. So far, i've got it working just as I want it to, where I can manually search a film, search TMDB using the API and save the film/studios in my db. What I want to do, however, is have an action called 'Scrape' that will, well, 'scrape' my media server for a list of movies, check if they exist in my db and if not, search these films on TMDB and save them automatically. I've also got this working...kind of.

For example, i'll have a List that will be looped through in the 'Scrape' controller, and this list is a list of movies that need to be searched, so:

- Avengers: Infinity War
- The Avengers
- Tron
- Harry Potter

I'm running the list through a foreach() loop, and for each item i'm going through the search procedure, and I can check how many results there are. Now this is where I run into my problem. If the length of the result is more than one, I need the user to be able to search through these results midloop, select a film then have the selected film be added. I'm able to cycle through my List and add all of the films that only have one result, but its the ones that have multiple. For example, 'Tron' is going to return more than one result, and the user needs to determine which version of Tron they wanted to add.

So this is the controller:

```
        List<string> items = NetworkScrape.ScrapeFolders();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //Results from the movie search
            SearchContainer<SearchMovie> Results = client.SearchMovieAsync(item).Result;
            if (Results.Results.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item + " could not be found.");
                continue;
            }
            if (Results.Results.Count == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item + " only has one entry, auto add.");
                MoviesSelectViewModel vm = new MoviesSelectViewModel
                {
                    TMDBid = Results.Results[0].Id
                };

                //Add the movie to the DB
                await Create(vm);
                continue;
            }
            if (Results.Results.Count > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item + " has more than one entry, manual input required.");
                //This is where the user would select the film
                continue;
            }
        }
```

I've only got all of the WriteLine's for testing purposes, and 'items' is the list of movies to search. The final use case down the bottom, if results is more than 1, is where I want to pass 'Results.Results' to a View where the user is shown a table of the search results, in which they can select, but I don't know how to make the foreach loop wait for that result from the view, and even if i could halt the loop i don't exactly know how I can let the loop know when it is okay to 'continue'. I tried await but you can't do that with a View so i'm really lost.

Sorry for the big, long post but I just thought i'd give as much information as I can to help illustrate my problem because i'm totally lost. Any help at all would be appreciated, or even a better way of doing this.

Comment: assuming this is asp.net, then i would process all that could be processed then return with a list of duplicates that the user then chooses from or selects.  you are in a request /response paradigm so waiting is not going to be the way to go

Comment: Well thats what i tried but i just ran into the same problem where i needed to loop through the list, return a view to get information from the user and keep doing that - but whenever i return a view it obviously doesnt stay in the loop. I dont know how to keep generating new views that will post information to the method that adds the movie, then keep looping to the next movie and so on. How else would i loop through this when i need to get information from the user for every entry?

Comment: @Hendo16: No. Run through the entire loop, saving the ones that are exact matches, and add dupes to some sort of collection as you come across them. Then return the view to the user with this collection to pick the right one from the dupes, and finally save their choices for just those items.